# Is there a way to set a value in one unit test that can be used by another

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a simple question, im creating a unit test class lets say it looks like this:

```
namespace Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ApiTest
    {
         private var x;

         [TestMethod]
         public testA()
         {
             some operactons
             x = some value
         }

         [TestMethod]
         public testB()
         {
             if(x == null)
                test fail
         }
    }
```

Now as presented above I am interested in, is it possible to set one value (x) in Test Method A so it could be used in Test Method B?

Comment: You probably don't want to do this. Unittests should run independently of each other.

Comment: Unit tests should be isolated from each other. If you need to share something global (constants,...), just declare as the class property. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ideally a unit test should be a "unit". It should be independent of any other tests. You could create a helper function that generates some generic data that could be accessed in both unit tests.

Comment: And, please, specify which unit-test framework do you use in tags.

Comment: If you use NUnit you can use method decorated with OneTimeSetUpAttribute and calculate x in this method. Then assert in in first test and use in test 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this by declaring var x as static:

```
private static var x;
```

But i wouldn't recommend to set the variable from a TestMethod. If "var x" is a variable you need in every other TestMethod (testC, testD, ...) then set it in the ClassInitialize(). This way var x is available for every TestMethod in your class ApiTest.

```
[TestClass]
public class ApiTest
{
     private static var x;

     [ClassInitialize()]
     public static void InitApiTest(TestContext context)
     {
         some operactons
         x = some value
     }

     [TestMethod]
     public testA()
     {
         //Obsolete
     }

     [TestMethod]
     public testB()
     {
         if(x == null)
            test fail
         else
            ...
     }
}
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer. The others deal with initializing a test, which does *not* allow people to set it in `methodA`.

Comment: @ Rob That's not the point. The point is Test B should not depend on Test A. We just don't want to propose anything to encourage an incorrect unit test approach.

Answer (score 1):

Like what has been suggested, you probably shouldn't do it in the first place. Unit test should be independent to each other. But You can set the prerequisites of your tests in either Test initializer or Class initializer, e.g.

```
private int x;

[TestInitialize]
public void Init()
{
    x = ...;
}
```

Test initializer will be executed before every test in the test class.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TestInitialize attribute to run code before running each test. The method with this attribute will be run before both test a and test b.

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize() 
{ 
    x = someValue;
}
```

If you only want to do it once before all tests, do it in the constructor.

[MSDN about Visual Studio unit tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182517(v=vs.100).aspx)